# AS3 go to next frame with hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to make a button that allows you to go to the next frame. I would like to do this with hitTestObject. When the charecter walks over the button, you should go to the next frame.

I have no idea how to do this, could someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite generic, hope this can help you

```
if (yourCharacter.hitTestObject(yourButton)) {
     nextFrame ();
 }
```